# Android screenshot of calling activity

Tags: android, android-activity, screenshot

I got an activity that gets the blurred screenshot of the calling activity as background. Actually I'm doing this whenever I start a new activity with and Intent extra.

But this seams not to be a good solution cause I always have to rewrite the code for pasing the bitmap to the new activity.

Is there another option? I'd like to get the screenshot of the "parent" activity wether through taking it's view or another thing I thought would be making the new view with an transparent background but it didn't work.

Comment: Try Fresco library or this https://github.com/facebook/screenshot-tests-for-android

Comment: Thanks, but how would the fresco lib help me? I still have to take the screenshot in activity A and pass it in an intent to activity B on starting it. Or have you got another idea with it? The screenshot test lib looks promising but its intended for testing purpose

Comment: Maybe you need to implement one ANdroid service, which would work in background and ask your app if class name was changed. If changed take a screenshot

Comment: I know when I have to take the screenshot so theres no need for extra checking. It's like changing the activity to activity -> take screenshot of Activity A (which is finishing at this moment). But how can I take the screenshot of Activity A from activity B

Comment: well, learn something about UI testing frameworks like robotium and you get an answer. I'm pretty sure the answer wouldbe "no, you can't take a screenshot of activity, which is not presented". I presented you the simplest way